# Raise error in php if the sum(amount) is greater than 25000 else insert it in database mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
$dupesql = "SELECT * FROM `transfer` WHERE 25000>=(select sum(amount) from transfer WHERE acc_no='$acc_no1') AND acc_no='$acc_no1' AND agent_id='$agent_id'";

echo "SELECT * FROM `transfer` WHERE 25000>=(select sum(amount) from transfer WHERE acc_no='$acc_no1') AND acc_no='$acc_no1' AND agent_id='$agent_id'";

$duperaw = mysql_query($dupesql);

if (mysql_num_rows($duperaw) > 0) {
   $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `transfer`(`t_id`, `agent_id`, `agent_name`, `date`, `name`, `phone`, `email`, `tname`, `tphone`, `temail`, `acc_no`, `bank`, `branch`, `code`, `amount`, `comment`, `status`) VALUES (NULL,'$agent_id','$agent_name','$date','$name','$phone','$email','$tname','$tphone','$temail','$accno','$bank','$branch','$code','$amt','$cmmnt','$status')");

echo '<script language="javascript">alert("Your Order has been Received \n You will be Notified via SMS/Email when the money is Transfered");window.location="../my.php"</script>';
```

Comment: What problem you are having which type of error is coming can please describe more about the same? \

Comment: its directly going to else condition.. & throwing error that "limit 25000 has been crossed !!"which i had given.
I want to compare the Sum(amount) with 25000 if it's less than 25000 thousand it should subtract the value for ex. 25000-sum(amount) i.e 20000 so it should raise error that "You 5000 amount is only remaining".
If sum(amount) is greater than 25000 it should raise error that "You had cross your limit of 25000"!!!

Comment: so any solution will be helpful??

Comment: Have you tried this query within SQL

Comment: As you have been using the aggregate_function() in phpmyadmin so there is  rule like that if you are using that function in your query you are bound to use Group BY and having clause in your query. Then i think that it should not give any error

Comment: yes its directly taking me to the error in else condition....!!!!

Comment: & i dont have idea of how to compare & raise error..!!